# Customizing Rocket bash on Mainframe (USS)

Tags: mainframe, zos

We have the Rocket Bash installed on our Mainframe. I am wondering if i can add customization in .bash_profile to change font size, colors etc.

I tried making typical updates in .bash_profile in my USS home directory to change font colors and did not see any difference.

Have any of you done that ?

Comment: How are you connecting to z/OS USS, and are you sure you’re using bash as your shell?

Comment: I usually ssh into my Z/OS USS . We have the Rocket Git port installed on my  mainframe and i believe it uses bash as the shell . Once i am in USS, i usually just type bash and then i get in there. I tried giving bash -version and it said GNU bash, Version 4.3.46(6)-release (i370-ibm-openedition), it is bash for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you’re running into the difference between .bash_profile and .bashrc, which, especially if you’re used to the behavior of Mac OS, is not intuitive. Basically, bash can be invoked in two ways; in a login context, and a non-login context (ie, executing /bin/bash manually). In the first case, bash sources the contents of .bash_profile; in the second case, it sources .bashrc.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346336/why-have-both-bash-profile-and-bashrc for much more information.

Short version is that since you’re executing bash manually, as opposed to updating your RACF profile to point to it, you need to put your settings in .bashrc, not .bash_profile.

Comment: Thanks . I will check tomorrow and then update here.

Comment: Yes , i tried putting some aliases in .bashrc and it worked . My original intent was to see if i can add color to my bash terminal in USS . Looks like that will need additional work  . [Found helpful link on medium that talks about that](https://medium.com/@sdearth/color-terminals-on-z-os-unix-system-services-6e9b3958af1b) . I wish xterm 256 color was available by default in USS.